# How do I skip default sorting in ng-repeat?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am displaying data I get from a json but ng-repeat display it in asc order I want to just display as it is in the json and skip sorting.

Here is my html:

```
    div ng-repeat="(key, data) in List">
     <div class="component-title">{{key}}</div>
     <div ng-repeat="(key, value) in data">
     <div ng-repeat="(key, item) in value">
     <div class="row test-label" ng-if="key === 'name'">
     <div class="pull-left">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ban-circle"></span>
      {{item}}
    </div>
    <div class="pull-right">
      <ul class="pull-right nav nav-pills">
        <li><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span></li>
        <li>|</li>
        <li><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ban-circle"></span></li>
         </ul>
        </div>
       </div>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
```

My `.js` file:

```
  (function () {
   'use strict';

  angular.module('main')
  .directive('chTest', function () {
    return {
    templateUrl: '/templates/chTestDirective.html',

    controller: ['$scope', function ($scope) {
      $scope.List = {
        n: [
        {
          is_enabled: false,
          status: '',
          id: 'set',
          name: 'set',
          result: ''
        },
        {
          is_enabled: false,
          status: 'failed',
          id: 'list_of_tests',
          name: 'list_of_tests',
          result: ''
        },
        {
          is_enabled: false,
          status: 'failed',
          id: 'single_test',
          name: 'single_test',
          result: ''
        },
        {
          is_enabled: false,
          status: 'passed',
          id: 'all_tests',
          name: 'all_tests',
          result: ''
        },
        {
          is_enabled: false,
          status: 'passed',
          id: 'specific_regex',
          name: 'specific_regex',
          result: ''
        }
        ],
        c: [
        {
          is_enabled: false,
          status: 'running',
          id: 'boot-runcommand-delete',
          name: 'bootruncommanddelete',
          result: ''
        },
        {
          is_enabled: false,
          status: 'failed',
          id: 'boot_runcommand_delete_custom_image',
          name: 'boot_runcommand_delete_custom_image',
          result: ''
        },
        {
          is_enabled: false,
          status: 'running',
          id: 'boot-runcommand-delete-with-disk',
          name: 'bootruncommanddeletewithdisk',
          result: ''
        }
        ],
        ce: [
        {
          is_enabled: false,
          status: '',
          id: 'create_delete_node_group_templates',
          name: 'create_delete_node_group_templates',
          result: ''
        },
        {
          is_enabled: false,
          status: 'running',
          id: 'create_scale_delete_cluster',
          name: 'create_scale_delete_cluster',
          result: ''
        },
        {
          is_enabled: false,
          status: 'failed',
          id: 'create_and_delete_cluster',
          name: 'create_and_delete_cluster',
          result: ''
        },
        {
          is_enabled: false,
          status: 'passed',
          id: 'create_and_list_node_group_templates',
          name: 'create_and_list_node_group_templates',
          result: ''
        }
        ],
        k: [
        {
          is_enabled: false,
          status: 'passed',
          id: 'boot',
          name: 'boot',
          result: ''
        },
        {
          is_enabled: false,
          status: 'failed',
          id: 'list-servers',
          name: 'listservers',
          result: ''
        }
        ],
        neutron: [
        {
          is_enabled: false,
          status: 'running',
          id: 'create-and-delete-node',
          name: 'createanddeletenode',
          result: ''
        },
        {
          is_enabled: false,
          status: 'passed',
          id: 'create-and-list-node',
          name: 'createandlistnode',
          result: ''
        }
        ],
        g: [
        {
          is_enabled: false,
          status: 'running',
          id: 'create-and-delete-image',
          name: 'createanddeleteimage',
          result: ''
        },
        {
          is_enabled: false,
          status: 'passed',
          id: 'create-and-list-image',
          name: 'createandlistimage',
          result: ''
        },
        {
          is_enabled: false,
          status: 'failed',
          id: 'create-image-and-boot-instances',
          name: 'createimageandbootinstances',
          result: ''
        },
        {
          is_enabled: false,
          status: 'failed',
          id: 'list_images',
          name: 'list_images',
          result: ''
        }
        ],
        s: [
        {
          is_enabled: false,
          status: 'passed',
          id: 'keystone',
          name: 'keystone',
          result: ''
        },
        {
          is_enabled: false,
          status: '',
          id: 'token_validate_cinder',
          name: 'token_validate_cinder',
          result: ''
        },
        {
          is_enabled: false,
          status: '',
          id: 'token_validate_neutron',
          name: 'token_validate_neutron',
          result: ''
        },
        {
          is_enabled: false,
          status: 'failed',
          id: 'token_validate_heat',
          name: 'token_validate_heat',
          result: ''
        },
        {
          is_enabled: false,
          status: 'passed',
          id: 'token_validate_glance',
          name: 'token_validate_glance',
          result: ''
        },
        {
          is_enabled: false,
          status: 'passed',
          id: 'token_validate_nova',
          name: 'token_validate_nova',
          result: ''
        }
        ],
        q: [
        {
          is_enabled: false,
          status: 'failed',
          id: 'nova-update-and-delete',
          name: 'novaupdateanddelete',
          result: ''
        },
        {
          is_enabled: false,
          status: 'running',
          id: 'nova-update',
          name: 'novaupdate',
          result: ''
        },
        {
          is_enabled: false,
          status: 'passed',
          id: 'neutron-update',
          name: 'neutronupdate',
          result: ''
        },
        {
          is_enabled: false,
          status: 'passed',
          id: 'cinder-update',
          name: 'cinderupdate',
          result: ''
        },
        {
          is_enabled: false,
          status: 'passed',
          id: 'cinder-update-and-delete',
          name: 'cinderupdateanddelete',
          result: ''
           }
           ]
           };
         }]
          };
          });
       })();
```

How can be this achieved? Thanks

Comment: What version of angularjs are you using? According to [this thread](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/6210) this issue was fixed in 1.4.

Comment: @Tony  i am using this v1.3.18

Comment: @Tony could you please guide me?

Comment: Just upgrade your version of angular to >1.4.x...

Answer (score 0):

In short: Upgrade to 1.4

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat

> You need to be aware that the JavaScript specification does not define
>   the order of keys returned for an object. (To mitigate this in Angular
>   1.3 the ngRepeat directive used to sort the keys alphabetically.)
>
> Version 1.4 removed the alphabetic sorting. We now rely on the order
>   returned by the browser when running for key in myObj. It seems that
>   browsers generally follow the strategy of providing keys in the order
>   in which they were defined, although there are exceptions when keys
>   are deleted and reinstated. See
>   https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete#Cross-browser_issues
>
> If this is not desired, the recommended workaround is to convert your
>   object into an array that is sorted into the order that you prefer
>   before providing it to ngRepeat. You could do this with a filter such
>   as toArrayFilter or implement a $watch on the object yourself.